# Html option and input field not displayed proper

Tags: html, reactjs

I have here a small react app that works fine but when i try to render teh option and input field it doesnt look right

```
render() {
    return (
          <div>
              <div>
                <select onChange={this.makeSelection} name="base" value={this.state.base}>
                  {this.currencies.map(currency => <option key={currency} value={currency}></option>)}
                </select>
                <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeValue}/>
              </div>
            <div>
              <select onChange={this.makeSelection} name="other" value={this.state.other}>
                  {this.currencies.map(currency => <option key={currency} value={currency}></option>)}
              </select>
              <input  disabled={true} value={this.state.converted} />
            </div>
          </div>
    );
```

and this is how it looks in the browser- i tried chrome and brave browser

this is a screenshot here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKUAj.jpg

and here is the code:
https://pastebin.com/55SHSSsd

Comment: What's not right? what do you want them to be?

Comment: i would like to see the options, like USD, GBP etc- i dont see anything, when i open the section or option menu its empty

Comment: So you don't have any data. This is you bug.

Comment: when i type in the number in the first input field i see it aswell as the result in the second input field, what i dont see is the selection/option menu with the currencies. the app works just fine- i just dont see the selecion items

Comment: you should be able to pick the currency you want to convert to and from like USD, GBP, CNY, INR and things like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass current element, currency as the content for the option tags:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={this.makeSelection}
        name="base"
        value={this.state.base}
      >
        {this.currencies.map((currency) => (
          <option key={currency} value={currency}>{currency}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeValue} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={this.makeSelection}
        name="other"
        value={this.state.other}
      >
        {this.currencies.map((currency) => (
          <option key={currency} value={currency}>{currency}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <input disabled={true} value={this.state.converted} />
    </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
```

References:

w3schools.com. HTML  Tag. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp. (accessed November 27, 2020).

Comment: @charliebrown You didn't add the currency element as content to your option tags. The What is an HTML Element section of this link: w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp shows what is meant by content.  The link my answer's reference gives an example how it is done with option tags.